# How to get local timezone on Flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, timezone, flutter-web

I want to get current timezone such as Europe/london.[flutter_native_timezone](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone) not works on web. how to get it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can still determine local timezone from `DateTime.now()`:

```dart
  print(DateTime.now().timeZoneName);
  print(DateTime.now().timeZoneOffset);
```

If you unhappy with previous result, we can use [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) through `dart:js` library:

```dart
import 'dart:js' as js;
//...
var dtf = js.context['Intl'].callMethod('DateTimeFormat');
var ops = dtf.callMethod('resolvedOptions');
print(ops['timeZone']);
```

Answer (score 1):

The package `flutter_native_timezone` [now supports web](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_timezone/changelog#1012) as well (via the [ECMAScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl)).